# Calculating r-squared manually with lagged variables

Tags: random-effects-model, r-squared, lags

I am in doubt with some methodological questions regarding the explanatory power of my model.

Im running a correlated random effects model in some panel data in which there are some lagged values, like below:

$\Delta Y_{i,t} = a + c_i + hT + B_1 X_{i,t} + B_2 X_{i,t-1} +...+ B_N mean(X)_i + B_{N+1} mean(X)_{i,t-1} +...+ \epsilon _i$

Where $c_i$ is the unobserved heterogeneity, $B_2$ and $B_{N+1}$ are the coefficients of the lagged values, $mean(X)_i$ represents the cross-sectional mean, in the style of Mundlak(1978), and hT represents year dummies.

As I wish to calculate the r-squared excluding the unobserved heterogeneity and the time-dummies of my model, to evaluate only the power of X on Y, I am constructing the variables manually and then calculating this version of r-squared by $Cor(X_{i},Y)^t*Cor(X_i,X_n)^{-1}*Cor(X_{i},Y)$.

My doubt is the following: should I exclude all the lines with NAs created by the lagged values and make the calculation only with the complete cases, or should I use all the lines that have at least one lagged value?

For example, for lag=5, should I exclude the first five lines to run my regression and to calculate r-squared or should I exclude only the first line (the one with NAs for all the lags)?

I was using only the complete cases, but when comparing the results with the lags generated inside the regression (in the call) by the package plm (in R) it shows a different value. For P = 20 years, and lag = 2, it shows T = 18-19.